# Install Ubuntu onto USB stick? (Not installer?)

Tags: boot, usb, usb-drive

I'm a total newbie, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I was wondering if I could make a version of Ubuntu I could run straight from the USB stick. Not like the installer, but I'd plug it in and it would be a full version of Linux that saves my stuff and all of that.

At first I tried plugging in 2 USB sticks into my computer. One empty one, one with the installer, and install from one onto the other. The installation took a few hours but went fine. However, once it said it was going to reboot, the whole computer crashed. I let it sit for about ten minutes before turning off the PC. When I turned it back on, it seemed fine, but I couldn't boot the USB stick I just installed Ubuntu onto. I can still boot the installer USB fine (I'm actually using the "Try Ubuntu" feature on it to write this), but the installed one doesn't work.

Now I just want to know if there's a straight-forward, newbie-friendly guide on how to make a bootable Ubuntu stick. All the official ones I could find were just for putting the installer on a USB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed it successfully on the microSD card on my phone and plug my phone into any PC and boot it from USB. It's no different to installing it on your laptop..... wasn't for me anyways.